# Take 4 bits out of an int and convert to byte

Tags: c#, byte, data-conversion

I am implementing a serial protocol.

I need to take class members and pack them into a `byte[]` message.

Protocol byte #7 goes like this:

**Bit 0-3** - SomeNumricData

**Bit 0-4** - OtherNumericData

I am trying to build byte #7 from class members :

```
commandData[7] = Convert.ToByte(

            Convert.ToByte(SomeNumricData) |
            Convert.ToByte(OtherNumericData) << 4
            );
```

I get:

> System.OverflowException: 'Value was either too large or too small for
> an unsigned byte

Since there is no 4 bits data type... How can I get only 4 bits out of the integer, to not overflow the `Convert.ToByte()`?

Comment: i usually use something like this to extract bits: `(_integer & (((1 << _bitsNum) - 1) << _bitOffset)) >> _bitOffset`

Comment: If you only want the lower 4 bits of an integer x do `x & 1111b`. 1111b in conjunction with the binary AND operator is a bit mask defining which bits to keep - here the lower 4.

Comment: Bit 0-3/Bit 0-4: so they are overlapping? Or do you mean Bit 0-3/Bit 4-7?

Comment: @ckuri in C#, the binary literal is `0b1111` (starting in C# 7, previously there was no binary literal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are providing a number that is overflowing. You could use the code bellow, but it will take only the four least significant bits. If the number is greater than 0x0F, the other bits will be ignored.

```
commandData[7] = Convert.ToByte((SomeNumricData & 0x0F) | ((OtherNumericData << 4) & 0xF0));
```

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thanks